# MySQL Java stored procedure gives error "Parameter index of 1 is out of range"

Tags: java, mysql

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Connection connection = getMySqlConnection();
        CallableStatement proc = connection.prepareCall("{ call LCD_GetDispInfoAllTimeTable() }");
        proc.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
        proc.execute();
        int returnValue = proc.getInt(1);
        System.out.println(returnValue + "");
//      conn.close();
      }


      public static Connection getMySqlConnection() throws Exception {
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String url = "";
        String username = "";
        String password = "";

        Class.forName(driver);
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        return conn;
      }
    }
```

When I run this code I see a Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index of 1 is out of range (1, 0) , why ?

This procedure return :

```
Niemstów 07 pętla   10  05:33:00    3673114 11558169    754378  1
NŻ Niemstów 05  16  05:35:00    3669905 11556510    754379  3
NŻ Niemstów 03  16  05:37:00    3666969 11555665    754380  3
```

My procedure ;

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `LCD_GetDispInfoAllTimeTable`()
BEGIN

    SELECT bs.name as bsName, tt.busstoptype as bsType, tt.time as ttTime, bs.longitude as lon, bs.latitude as lat, tt.timetable_id as ttID, 
    Bus_Stop_Status_GET( tt.timetable_id, bst.timetable_id, bst.busstate_id ) as bus_stop_status -- 0 zrobiony, 1 - aktualny, 2- pomiędzy, 3 następne
    FROM (SELECT * FROM  mpk_currentbusstate ORDER BY changestime desc LIMIT 1 )bst
    join mpk_timetable t ON( bst.timetable_id = t.timetable_id )
    join mpk_timetable tt ON ( t.linelogin_id  = tt.linelogin_id AND t.line_id = tt.line_id AND t.brigade = tt.brigade AND t.rate = tt.rate 
        and t.schedudle_id = tt.schedudle_id)
    LEFT JOIN mpk_busstop bs ON (bs.busstop_id = tt.busstop_id)
    LEFT JOIN mpk_busstate bt ON( bst.busstate_id = bt.busstate_id );

END
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the parameter in your call String:

`CallableStatement proc = connection.prepareCall("{ call LCD_GetDispInfoAllTimeTable(?) }");`

Notice that `?`, it says that there is a parameter to be set. Now it knows that there is a parameter to be set, just like methods in Java or some other language. If you wanted to use multiple parameters you can write multiple `?`, like: `...LCD_GetDispInfoAllTimeTable(?, ?, ?)`.

Comment: Why I have to specify the parameter in my call if my procedure don't have parametrs ? when i start his procedure in mysql I don't set a parametrs

Comment: It does have parameters, output parameters are also parameters.

Comment: So can you tell me how I can get all rows ?

Comment: When I do this  CallableStatement proc = connection.prepareCall("{ call mpklocal.LCD_GetDispInfoAllTimeTable(?) }");
     proc.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR); I see this same alert

Comment: Does your stored procedure have the output parameter on SQL side?

Comment: Your procedure doesn't return anything, you need to add a output parameter to it and return what you selected. You are setting a type in java as `Types.VARCHAR` so you will need to return it as varchar from procedure. It's completely a different question tho, ask it in another thread :)

Comment: Could you show me how it have to look , a procedure and call a procedure ?

Comment: Everything is fine on Java side (from your post in the comment above, not in the main post) and all you need to do it edit SQL side and that depends a lot on what SQL you are working on and I'm not really good at SQL, probably would make some mistake. Ask another question with something like 'How can I return all selected rows as Varchar from SQL procedure', remember to describe your problem, it's purely an SQL question so you don't need to mention the Java.

Answer (score 0):

as far as your procedecure declaration is concerned, its code is:

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `LCD_GetDispInfoAllTimeTable`()
 BEGIN
 SELECT bs.name as bsName, tt.busstoptype as bsType, tt.time as ttTime,
 bs.longitude as lon, bs.latitude as lat, tt.timetable_id as ttID, 
 Bus_Stop
```

where the procedure definition does NOT contain any parameter definition, 
so setParameter or registerOutParameter, cannot be applied for this procedure